# How to create schema only from SQL Server 2012 backup file

Tags: sql-server-2012, database-restore, large-data

I have a backup file which is over 150gb. I am trying to create a new database from a backup. But it failed with the following exception:

> Create Database or Alter database failed because the resulting cumalative database size
>   would exceed your licensed limit of 10240 MB per database

As there is restriction of max 10 GB for SQL Server Express, is there any way to create only the schema (stored procedures, functions etc) from the backup file, and not the data.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no "schema-only" restore. But you have several other options:

- Download and install an instance of [Evaluation Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29066), restore your database there, and extract the things you need. Then uninstall the instance of Evaluation Edition.
- Buy Developer Edition and use that, permanently, instead of Express. You should be able to find this at your favorite software retailer. [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007RFXQAM) has it for $43.99; [Microsoft has it too](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/en_US/pd/SQL-Server-2012-Developer-Edition/productID.249344600) but they charge full price ($59.95).
- Try out some of these 3rd party tools that let you "attach" a backup as if it were a database ([Red Gate has one](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-virtual-restore/); Quest may also have similar functionality with [LiteSpeed](http://www.quest.com/litespeed-for-sql-server/)). With Express Edition though it may be subject to the same size limitation, I haven't tried, and I'm not sure if the trial editions of those products have any limitations either.

Answer (score 1):

To create a database with an empty schema I can suggest two options:

1) In SSMS, right click on the database in the Object Explorer, go to Tasks/Generate Scripts and run through the wizard to generate a sql script to create a new database with the same schema.

2) Use Red Gate SQL Compare, put the database in the left hand side data source, and select 'Create Database' on the right hand side of the comparison. Run through the comparison and Deployment Wizard to create a new database based on the schema of the source database.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but it popped as the first result in a search for me. SQL Server Developer edition is now free through Visual Studio Dev Essentials. You can download 2017 Developer [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads) for all your large database needs!